# Where to start for NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been working with standalone applications for past 2 years, and have lost touch with all sorts of web applications/services. I heard this NodeJS,AngularJS being popular amongst my peers, where to begin from? I have an interview for NodeJS 4 days later? Tell me all that I should read and please suggest a small project too that I can do on it to learn well? Thanks..

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same languages. Java is to JavaScript the same as ham is to hamster (that means nothing)

Comment: i don't want to crush your dreams but if you are not fluent in javascript i'd suggest not searching for a nodejs position right now. you should throw some money at some courses and maybe in one month you are capable enough to get into a simple position. there are alot of issues you'll come across. mostly language specific. you really have to understand js quite well to avoid writing flawed code.

Comment: Okay GottZ. I get your point. But I have used Javascript previously, like 2 years ago. So maybe If I revisit the concepts, that may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my personal experience I think that you should start to learn about the core of Node.JS both C++ and JavaScript, how it integrates with the V8 Engine (Javascript interpreter) and what new language features were implemented and why they are what makes Node.JS an amazing environment and Javascript an Server Side Language.

Then learn why they call itself  asynchronous and event-driven framework. This is essential to learn how the framework works.

Go deep into module.export and require function

Have fun understanding how NPM packages work together

But as long as you only have 4 days I would recommend you to buy a proper course in Udemy or something like, grab some bags of your favorite Doritos flavor, some beverages and get in love with Node.JS

Comment: Thanks a ton Amaro. Much of a motivation. I'll join in to udemy.